# Problems with proxy and problems with creating/running Angular applications using Angular CLI

Tags: angularjs, proxy, angular-cli

After updating Angular CLI I have problems with creating/running Angular applications using Angular CLI.  I tried to reinstall node, to reinstall CLI, to install old versions of node and CLI. All the time I received these errors:[image: Errors]. Can you help me with this problem? I'm addicted to Angular, so it's a very big problem for me.